# Apache Kafka Data Status ( Message Status )

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, messaging

I am a beginner in kafka and is trying to create a *chat application with the features like forward,read,delivered.*

Let me give my approaches first so that you would have an idea on whether I am going on the right path,

**Approach 1:**

- Define Topic 'some_name' having 3 partitions.
- These partitions denotes the below,

  - Partition 1 : Send
  - Partition 2 : Delivered
  - Partition 3 : Read

Here the messages will go through 1st partiton then once client provides a call back we dequeue it from the first queue and enqueue it to the 2nd and so on for the read part

**Approach 2:**

In this approach it would be just 1 topic and a partition and if Kafka provides a flag for each data present ( flag denoting if it has been consumed by any consumer ) , I can set that flag for read/delievered.

**What I have tried:**
I have tried going with the first approach as by maintaining 3 partitions but on the consumer side. I wasn't able read data from all 3 partitions together instead returning null.

These are the approaches that I have in mind and looking forward to explore more. I could really use a help on new approaches or the best way to overcome this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by consumer returning nulls. The default behavior of subscribing to a topic is getting assigned all partitions.

But you cannot "dequeue" data and move records across topic partitions, regardless, so you may want to reconsider your design, such as using the Transactional Outbox Pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I do consider the outbox pattern, so I will have to add the data first into db and then push to the queue. But here the challenge is how would we change the status of message of being from sent,delivered,read?

Comment: You can have multiple database tables. Or you can send update queries to one table with a "status" column... No messages should be `read` without first being delivered... Unclear to me what the difference between "sent" and "delivered" is. Also, that was only one possible pattern that can be used. My main point is that Kafka does not de-queue data upon consumption.